# How to use an LDPC encoder implemented in C in MATLAB and which (open source) encoder is most energy-efficient?

Tags: c, software-implementation, ldpc

I am looking for an open source LDPC encoder available online as I just have to use it for encoding raw bits to LDPC-encoded data to estimate the energy consumption. Which is the best encoder from the point of view of lower energy consumption? Also, how to use C files in MATLAB? It will be helpful if the answer includes some sample code or references. Thank you.

I have found some project files on Cihat Kececi's [GitHub](https://github.com/cihatkececi/ChannelCodingProjectList), but I am finding it difficult to select. Also, I am unaware of its use. Can someone please help me? Where could I find some references for proper understanding?